# monotonicity of a univariate function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, monotone-functions

I am considering the function
$$
f(x) = (a + e^x)^{-b} + (a + e^{-x})^{-b}
$$
where $a, b \in (0, \infty)$. What are the conditions on $a$ and $b$ that make $f(x)$ monotonic? Straightforward differentiation reduces it to showing that the transcendental equation
$$
{a y + y^2 \over a y + 1} = y^{2 \over 1 + b}
$$
has no solution on $(1, \infty)$. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Increasing/decreasing over which sets? $f(x)$ is an even function, so it is not monotonic over the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Since the questioner at the end is mentioning the interval $(1,\infty)$ for $y$, it means he is interested in $(0,\infty)$ for $x$ not the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh: that probably is the most reasonable interpretation, but I would like the OP to clearly state it.

Comment: Anyway, for $a=3$ and $b=2$ we have equality between $\frac{ay+y^2}{ay+1}$ and $y^{\frac{2}{b+1}}$ at $y\approx 18$.

Comment: Thank you guys for your inspirations. So I think the right question to ask is the following: What are the conditions on $a, b$ that make $f(x)$ montonic? The transcendental equation reformulation is still valid. If $b$ is a rational number i.e. $b=p/q$, the equation can be reduced to $a z^{2q+p} + z^q - z^{2p+q} - a z^p = 0$. Can one use polynomial theories to find the conditions on $a, p, q$? I obtained the above equation by leting $y = z^{p+q}$.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily monotone for small $a$. The only reason it appeared to be monotone is because when $a$ is sufficiently large, the $(a+e^{−x})^{−b}$ term is effectively constant.

It would be interesting to see if the exact value of $a$ for which $f$ on $(0,\infty)$ is monotone can be found.

[image: non-monotone]